# generate main div id dynamically using html and jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I want that #roww id should be unique at every time... like roww1, roww2 and so on please help. Thank u. That roww is mine main container...............
i dont want make unique id of inner div i.e discount tariff, actual tariff, etc... just need unique id of roww

```js
  var i = 1;
  var row = $('#row-container').clone();
$('#addButton').data('#roww',row);
$('#addButton').click(function(){
  $('#row-container').append($(this).data('#roww').clone());
});
$('#removeButton').click(function(){
  $('#row-container #roww').eq(  $('#row-container #roww').length-1 ).remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="select-box">
  <input type='button' class="btn btn-primary" value='Add Loaction' id='addButton'>
  <input type='button' class="btn btn-danger" value='Remove' id='removeButton'>
</div><br>

<div id="row-container">
  <div id="roww">
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="location" name="size" placeholder="Location" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="apt_name" name="clr" placeholder="Apartment Type" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
  
  <div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="act_tariff" name="qty" placeholder="Actual Tariff" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="dcnt_tariff" name="qty" placeholder="Discount Tariff" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
  
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: For what reason do you need to use incremental `id` attributes? It's generally considered to be an anti pattern. DOM traversal is a much better solution, if you're trying to identify the grouping element

Comment: Thank u bro rory for reply... i just need that my main div should be unique id... at anyhow should be fine please help me out thanku

Answer (score 0):

Try to make it with a counter variable incrementing on each click to make a unique id:

```js
var cont= 0
$('#addButton').click(function(){
  var newId= "roww"+cont
  console.log(newId)
  $('span').append("<br>");
  $('span').append($('.row-container:first').clone());
  $('.row-container:last').find("#roww").attr("id",newId);
  cont++
  
});
$('#removeButton').click(function(){
  $('.row-container:last').remove();
  cont--
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="select-box">
  <input type='button' class="btn btn-primary" value='Add Loaction' id='addButton'>
  <input type='button' class="btn btn-danger" value='Remove' id='removeButton'>
</div><br>

<div class="row-container">
  <div id="roww">
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="location" name="size" placeholder="Location" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="apt_name" name="clr" placeholder="Apartment Type" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
  
  <div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="act_tariff" name="qty" placeholder="Actual Tariff" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="dcnt_tariff" name="qty" placeholder="Discount Tariff" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
  
</div>
</div>
</div>
<span></span>
```

Comment: Thank You so much SilverSurfer <3

Comment: Is this fine if i use in php ? it seems .net(i see console there)

Comment: Yeah is it fine if you use the same elements/id

Comment: i just click the upper one :D now i did green